# Numpy and Scipy must be installed for TVRegDiag to work - aborting

Tags: numpy, amazon-ec2, scipy

I have installed `Numpy` and `Scipy` in an ubuntu EC2 instance. However, whenever I try to run any algorithm which has imported these modules, I keep on getting this one line of error `Numpy and Scipy must be installed for TVRegDiag to work - aborting`. What does this really mean.

Comment: perhaps, TVRegDiag may require a particular version of numpy as well as scipy that has API version matched to that numpy.

Comment: not really sure on how to check this

Answer (score 0):

it must be an `ImportError` according to the source code here http://math.lanl.gov/~rick/Software/TVDiff/tvregdiff.py

So, the python interpreter that you are using to launch your script is using some other python in the system which has no numpy or scipy.

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

do you have something like above in the first line of your code? And that's pointing to the right python version where you installed numpy/scipy?